# I'm using unpack in structure module in python and now getting errors

Tags: python, unpack

I'm now making a ransom-like program for my school project by using python module-struct, and there is struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes. I don't know why this is happening; because I was fixing codes in Github-it was not working in my computer-to understand how it works. And it does not work. At first, there was a problem in glob function and I fixed it, and I never touched this part.

I'm not used to using the struct module and didn't know how to use this function; so I tried to put only integer and remove 'infile.read(struct.calcsize('Q')) or insert '<' in front of Q in calcsize, or put only struct.calcsize('Q'). I also read docs and tried to understand how to use this and fix the problem but to my shame, I failed.

```py
def decrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename = None, chnksize = 64*1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
        iv = infile.read(16)
        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        #chunksize = 16
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

            outfile.truncate(origsize)
```

It expected to decode the encoded file and firstly, it must calculate it's original size but it only spit out the error message-struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes.

It is the original error message:

```
C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\for Test\jmtree_44520.jpg .sasya
Decrypting> C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\for Test\jmtree_44520.jpg.sasya
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 62, in <module>
    decrypt_file(key, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 32, in decrypt_file
    origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in `struct.calcsize('Q')`. It must give `8` for the function `struct.unpack` to work. What value do you get on your machine? Replace it with just `8` (int not string). `I never touched this part` - maybe you should start with the purpose/logic of the code?

Comment: @Poolka
it also gives me only error message:
```
C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\for Test\jmtree_44520.jpg .sasya
Decrypting> C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\for Test\jmtree_44520.jpg.sasya
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 62, in <module>
    decrypt_file(key, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 32, in decrypt_file
    origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(struct.calcsize(8)))[0]
TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be a str or bytes object, not int
```
And I think I write words that you can misunderstand;

Comment: I mean I just not touched its main structure. I think you mean I should start with the module's purpose/logic, right? If it means I should start with the purpose of this code I bring, I want to say I already,.

Comment: Replace with 8 means `origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(8))[0]` - read 8 bytes from file then unpack bytes into values.

Comment: @Poolka I mean, I do that. it just gives me the error message- `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 62, in <module>
    decrypt_file(key, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Yeeun\Desktop\test\RansomTest.py", line 32, in decrypt_file
    origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(8))[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
[Finished in 0.558s]`

Comment: Then I guess you can't read 8 bytes from your file. Maybe it is of size, say, 12 bytes. So you read 8 bytes - it's ok, then you read 4 bytes - it's not ok and you get the error. You may 1) read 8 bytes -> check length -> unpack 2) add try/except 3) read whole file -> iterate over data with 8-byte step.